# Python 3.8 (Luhn's Algorithm Alternative): How do I convert a list into a string?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, luhn

My question is this: How do I convert a list into a string, particularly when it comes to a print command?

I am attempting a variant of the Luhn's Algorithm program where I assess whether student IDs are valid or not. With much help from the internet, I mainly go this to work. However, I have one final hurdle in that, with use of an f-string, I supposed to end by printing out the ID number that the user gave me.

The problem is that I convert their input from a string to a list in order to run the algorithm, but I am currently unable to reverse the process.

Here is my relevant code:

```
ide = input("Hello.\nWelcome to the University of Zac Sign-In Page.\nPlease enter your Identification Number:")

if len(ide) != 6 and len(ide) != 10:
    print(f"I'm sorry, but {ide} is an invalid Identification Number.")
    print("Please try again... If the Headmaster Zac ever figures out how to program such an action.")
    
else:
    print("Yey.\n\nProcessing:")
    print(ide)
    
    ide = list(ide)
    print(ide)
    
    end_ide_nums = []
    
    for place, num in enumerate(ide):
        
        if place % 2 == 0:
            #print("Even!")
            double_ide_nums = int(num)*2
            if double_ide_nums > 9:
                double_ide_nums = double_ide_nums - 9
                # doubel_ide_nums = str(double_ide_nums)
                # double_ide_nums_1 = double_ide_nums[0]
                # double_ide_nums_2 = double_ide_nums[1]
                # end_ide_nums.append(int(double_ide_nums_1))
                # end_ide_nums.append(int(double_ide_nums_2))
                #C: The above was an attempt to make my code more different than my reference's (teclado's) code, but I could not get
                #       it to work. I kept getting syntax errors, particularly with the use of 'else:', and the explanations
                #       were not clear enough to me for me to fix the issue.
            end_ide_nums.append(double_ide_nums)
            
        else:
                end_ide_nums.append(int(num))
    
                         
    total = sum(end_ide_nums)
    
    print(total)
    
    if total % 10 == 0:
        ide = str(ide)
        print(f"{ide}--------VALID!")
    else:
        ide = str(ide)
        print(f"{ide}--------INVALID!")
```

For example, here is what I want to get out of this if my input is 5555555555:

```
5555555555--------VALID!
```

However, here is what my actual result is:

```
['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5']--------VALID!
```

Please note that I did look at other similar questions and the answers given, but the problems are different enough (and my ignorance strong enough) that I was not helped by them. I apologize for the daftness, but I did at least attempt due diligence.

Any and all help is appreciated. Below are some extra resources:

> [Here is a screenshot of my code and its output using Spyder 4 with python 3.8.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQztq.png)

> [Note that I am heavily indebted to teclado for much of the progress that I made.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGutqiC-REw)

Comment: @KenWhite Okay, I have taken the tour, read the most relevant Q-and-As from the help center, updated my prior beliefs about this site and its community accordingly, and am trying to take your comment and edits in good faith.  Thank you for the advice and links. I'll remember them for my next post. Still, my actual coding question is unanswered. Do you have any answers or at least guidance for that?

Comment: Well, it seems to me that since the user originally input a string into `ide` that the simplest solution to the problem you're having is not to use `ide = list(ide)` to convert it to a list, but to use a different variable to store the list (like maybe `idelist`). That would mean that `ide` remains a string, and you can print it at the end when you need it.